# wpf horizontalalignment left and stretch?

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment

I Want to change border size to parent's size, but only grow to Maximum size.

If height and width is under 50 then horizontal and vertiacl will be stretched.
But after it reach to 50, it changes to center with height and width size 50 fixed

Forexample if it reached to 50, it looks like this

```
|  □  |
```

But What i want is this

```
|ㅁ   |
```

My xaml code here

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  MaxHeight="50" MaxWidth="50">
```

Comment: Could you put the Border inside the Grid (Grid with two or three-column) ?, then if you put a border on the first column then the border will consider the centre of the first column, and it will automatically show on the left side. |ㅁ C1 |  C2   |

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Shubham Sahu's answer helped me

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MaxWidth="10"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" MaxWidth="60"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Setting MaxWidth to Column definition solved this problem!